# Google Script get input from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an add on I'm creating and I need to be able to get content from an html page and then do some background work with what is entered into the text box. Here is what I have, any ideas? Please note that I know for a fact that the Google Script code is 100% functioning correctly after the line 6, the line that contains 'var studentIDResponse = removalForm.removalNameID', as I tested it with the alerts and prompts and it was working fine. The main problem is that it seems like when I press the remove button, which would be the submit button, nothing appears to take place.

```js
function processForm(removalForm){
      var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Loading Page').setTitle('Farragut FANS- Admin Portal');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Farragut FANS- Admin Portal');
      var mentor = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySheetIDIsHere').getSheetByName('Mentor Applications')
      var mentorData = mentor.getRange('A1:AA500').getValues()
      var studentIDResponse = removalForm.removalNameID
      var testOne = studentIDResponse.indexOf(' ')
      if (testOne >= 0){
        var length = studentIDResponse.length
        var studentIDResponse = studentIDResponse.subString(0,(length-1))
        }
      var testTwo = studentIDResponse.indexOf(' ')
      if (testTwo >= 0){
        var length = studentIDResponse.length
        var studentIDResponse = studentIDResponse.subString(0,(length-1))
        }
      var numberMatched = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < mentorData.length; i++){
        var row = mentorData[i]
        var studentID = row[8]
        var lastName = row[2]
        var lastName = lastName.toUpperCase()
        var studentIDResponse = studentIDResponse.toUpperCase()
        var lastNameMatch = studentIDResponse.indexOf(lastName)
        var studentIDMatch = studentIDResponse.indexOf(studentID)
      if (lastNameMatch >= 0 && lastName != '' || studentIDMatch >= 0 && lastName != ''){
          if (numberMatched==0){
            var removalOne = 'Student Name: '+row[1]+' '+row[2]+' Student ID: '+row[8]
          }
          if (numberMatched==1){
            var removalTwo = ', Student Name '+row[1]+' '+row[2]+' Student ID: '+row[8]
          }
          if (numberMatched==2){
            var removalThree = ', Student Name '+row[1]+' '+row[2]+' Student ID: '+row[8]
          }
          if (numberMatched==3){
            var removalFour = ', Student Name '+row[1]+' '+row[2]+' Student ID: '+row[8]
          }
          if (numberMatched==4){
            var removalFive = ', Student Name '+row[1]+' '+row[2]+' Student ID: '+row[8]
          } 
          numberMatched++
        } 
      }
      if (numberMatched == 0){
        var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Removal By ID Failure 1.0').setTitle('Farragut FANS- Admin Portal');
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Farragut FANS- Admin Portal');
      }
      if (numberMatched == 1){
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        var proceeding = ui.alert("Awesome! I was able to find one match in the system. I just want to confirm, I should remove this student correct? "+removalOne, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)
        if (proceeding == ui.Button.YES){
          var mentor = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySheetIDIsHere').getSheetByName('Mentor Applications')
          var mentorData = mentor.getRange('A1:AA500').getValues()
          var rowsDeleted = 0
          for (var i = 0; i < mentorData.length; i++){
            var row = mentorData[i]
            var studentID = row[8]
            var lastName = row[2]
            var lastName = lastName.toUpperCase()
            var studentIDResponse = studentIDResponse.toUpperCase()
            var lastNameMatch = studentIDResponse.indexOf(lastName)
            var studentIDMatch = studentIDResponse.indexOf(studentID)
            if (lastNameMatch >= 0 && lastName != '' || studentIDMatch >= 0 && lastName != ''){
              mentor.deleteRow((i+1)-rowsDeleted)
              ui.alert(removalOne+' has been removed from the system')
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="code.gs">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><img style="float: right;" src="http://gdurl.com/7Azn" alt="FANS Logo" width="150" height="150" /></p>
    <p>What is that student ID or the last name of the mentor that needs to be removed? Please put only one identifier, last name or student ID.</p>
    <div>
    <form id="removalForm">
      <input type="text" style="width: 150px;" id='removalNameID' name="removalNameID"/>
      <p></p>
      <input type="button" value="Remove" 
        onClick="google.script.run.processForm(this.form)" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel"
        onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <p class="secondary" style="text-align: right;">Version 2.0</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have your checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: I figured out my issue. I had accidentally saved two functions with the name processForm